# applying a rule once only child selector maybe?

Tags: css

```
#mainContent .container{
    background-image:url("/images/index_33.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding-left:85px;
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

how can only apply those rules to the first div with a class container?

Answer (score 1):

To "apply those rules to the first div with a class container", you need to be a little more specific `div.container`, and then use the `first-child` pseudo class.

```
#mainContent div.container:first-child {
    background-image:url("/images/index_33.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding-left:85px;
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

From [w3scools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pseudo_first-child.asp):

> The :first-child pseudo-class adds a style to an element that is the first child of another element.

Comment: Maybe it was that crafty @sdleihssirhc with his alternative views :)

Answer (score 0):

use the `:first-child` pseudo class:

```
#mainContent div.container:first-child {
  /* CSS rules here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.container div:first-child {
 /* ... */
}
```

Comment: That is incorrect. That will apply the css rules to the first child div of an element with a class of `container`.

Comment: Yes, I know. I thought that was the question. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

All these answer are wrong, I think. You need to use the `first-of-type` pseudo-class, **not** `first-child`.

Comment: That *would* work, but it is not supported in any current versions of Internet Explorer

Comment: Possibly true, the question is ambiguous. However an id would work better instead of the `first-of-type` pseudo class, which is why it is probably not used very often.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

**Please Note:** For :first-child to work in IE, a DOCTYPE must be declared.([more info](http://s11.cc/h6lq))

```
#mainContent .container div:first-child {
    background-image:url("/images/index_33.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding-left:85px;
    margin-top:10px;
}
```